# VMware PowerCLI command/script to see if a VM can run in a resource pool?

Tags: vmware, powercli

Is there PowerCLI script - or a series of commands - that can be used to determine if a VMs resource pool has enough available resources to start the VM WITHOUT triggering a vSphere error?

For performance testing reasons, we use a resource pool with maximums for RAM and CPU.  Each VM in the pool has a reservation set for CPU and RAM.  Testing automation will attempt to start as many VMs as possible in the pool when testing.  The CLI will return an error when starting the VM will exceed the amount of allowed resources.  When that happens, an error is shown on the vSphere console "Insufficient resources".  Instead of constantly starting the VM, failing, and generating the error - is there a way to check to see if there is enough space?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about CPU usage but you could use PowercLI get-stat on memory and base some logic around it. Quick example:

```
connect-viserver my_vc

$active = (get-stat -entity (get-cluster cluster_name | get-resourcepool Low) -stat mem.active.average -maxsamples 1 -realtime).Value
$granted = (get-stat -entity (get-cluster cluster_name | get-resourcepool Low) -stat mem.granted.average -maxsamples 1 -realtime).Value

$active
$granted

$pctused = ($active / $granted)*100
$pctused

# 4445929
# 31797248
# 13.9821188299063
```

I guess you could run this before building and use $pctused in the conditional statement e.g. if ($pctused -lt 98) { # build } else { # stop gracefully }